# zindex + jquery: How to make my menu appear over the jquery script?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a simple site but I'm just blocking on this weird bug (?) that puts my "hover" menu UNDER the jquery/iframe div.

[url removed. thanks for your answers!]

When the page opens, it's the first menu item on the top left. As you see, it appears under the images below and I have no clue how to fix this!

Is it my CSS, DIVs of jquery that is the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.menuruban { z-index: 1; }
.zoneimg { z-index: 0; }
```

Comment: You have to be kidding me. I have lost literally hours trying to ugly-force-fix this with all kind of javacripts. I don't understand why this works, isn't .zoneimg **after** .menuruban ? So by default, browser should put them zindex=0 and the next zindex=1 ?

Comment: @Rock, `z-index` is relative to its parent. Since `.zoneimg` and `.menuruban` are in the same parent giving 1 a higher `z-index` will make it apear ontop of the other.

Answer (score 0):

Just set your z-index to a higher value:

```
#menu li {
    z-index: 99; /* Or any other value higher than the images' z-index */
}
```

Or attach the z-index to the class `menuruban`:

```
.menuruban {
    z-index: 99; /* Or any other value higher than the images' z-index */
}
```